# how to make a list out of a input read-line in racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I want to make a list to be input out of the standard ouput to be used as a list

```
(define USER_INPUT  (list (read-line)))
```

when I input the list, I keep getting this error because the list to be input it;s use in a procedure of map

```
map: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: "10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10"
```

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that `(read-line)` yields a string, so you just end up with a list of one string element. If you specifically want to read in a list of numbers, split the string on whitespace and convert all the elements to numbers.

```
(map string->number (string-split (read-line)))
```

On the other hand, if you actually want to read in a list with the full power of Racket's syntax, you can use [`read`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html?q=split#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29).

```
> (read)
(10 10 10)
'(10 10 10)
```

If you want to specify list *contents* but don't want to include the parentheses, well, you can do that, too.

```
(read (open-input-string (format "(~a)" (read-line))))
```

Comment: thank you so much Alexis! I am new at Racket, I have been playing with it for a couple of weeks now. you're very helpful

Comment: For the latter case, you can also do `(sequence->list (with-input-from-string (read-line) in-port))` or even just `(with-input-from-string (read-line) in-port)` if a sequence suffices.